# How can I pass TotalRowCount to DataPager

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I've searched high and low and haven't found the right answer, so my last resort is to bother you guys.

I am using .NET Web Forms C# and Linq.

I am pulling back a large amount of records from the database, for this example it would be 500k records.

Now I need to page this data in the most efficient way, with a page size of 50 records. My Ling query will pass in the .Skip and .Take within the IQueryable but my asp:DataPager is only brining back one page of data as I'm unsure on how to pass the TotalRowCount to it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DataPager.TotalRowCount - Gets the total number of records that are retrieved by the underlying data source object that is referenced by the associated data-bound control.
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datapager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx